# How do I stop search engine opening instead of outlook e-mail in Windows 10 when I click on an e-mail address in a database excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook

Since loading Window 10, every time I select an e-mail address in an excel spreadsheet windows 10 opens the search engine. Previous to Windows 10 outlook e-mail would open so I can send an e-mail to the selected address

Comment: Have you checked you default client for mail to see if this may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do a search on "default programs" and select it from the results or go to

Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs

Select "Associate a file type or protocol with a program"

Scroll all the way to the bottom where you will find protocols and in particular the "mailto" protocol.  Hit the change program button and select the program you want.